# Looping through Months and counting rows

Tags: r

I have a df with three columns: StartDate, EndDate and SubscriptionType.

`df = data.frame(StartDate = as.Date(c('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-03-01')),
                EndDate = as.Date(c('2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-02-28')),
                SubscriptionType = c('monthly', 'monthly', 'yearly', 'yearly', 'yearly'))`

As example, by using this code:

```
df %>% filter(StartDate <= ymd('2018-5-15') & EndDate >= ymd('2018-5-15')) %>% count()
```

I get how many Subscriptions are active in the month of May.

I would like to print the results for every month in 2018 and store it in a data frame.

So far, I tried using this code:

```
z = NULL

m = c(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)

for (i in m) {z = rbind(z, data.frame(df %>% filter(StartDate <= ymd('2018-i-15') & EndDate >= ymd('2018-i-15')) %>% count()))}
```

but what I get are 24 warnings and a data frame z populated only with zeros.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably you can use `month()` from `lubridate` package and some `dplyr`, can you post something like `dput(df)`?

Comment: Do you mean the start dates or end dates should be in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group use `map` to do this.  Create the 'm' as a `Date` class object with `paste` and then `filter` the dataset based on the condition and apply the `count`

```
m <- ymd(paste0('2015-', sprintf('%02d', 1:12), '-15'))
map_df(m, ~ 
       df %>%      
         filter(Start_Date <=  .x & EndDate  >= .x) %>% 
         count)
```

Comment: @vhcandido  Looks like you removed the comment.  Couldn't read it

Comment: I was going to edit your answer and thought a comment would be better, but then I ran into a minor logic error in the original question and decided to add a new answer. +1'ed your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

`ymd('2018-i-15')`  does not a yield a `date` object. You have passed `ymd()` a string that has `2018` as year, `i` as month and `15` as day. The `i` in this case is fixed, and not replaced by the loop variable `i`. This is why you get the error `All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`, which is essentially telling you it cannot identify a date with `i` as the month.

To keep `i` variable, try `ymd(paste0("2018-", i, "-15"))`.

```
for (i in m) {
     z = rbind(z, data.frame(df %>% filter(StartDate <= ymd(paste0("2018-", i, "-15")) & EndDate >= ymd(paste0("2018-", i, "-15"))) %>% count()))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving @akrun's answer, that provided the simplest and direct solution to the looping problem.

However, if you expect to get `TRUE` for any month overlapping the interval between two dates it'd be better to convert them to months instead of using some fixed day. You can test it for some row containing `'2018-05-16'` and `'2018-06-14'` (start and end dates, respectively), it wouldn't count for `'2018-05'` neither for `'2018-06'` with the original condition.

```
f <- '%Y-%m'  # it'll be used a few times

m <- seq(ymd(180101), ymd(191231), by='month')
m <- format(m, f)  # 'e.g. 2018-05'

# purrr::map_dfr() works like apply, it'll map each value from m into .x
# inside the expression and use dplyr::bind_rows() to concatenate the
# resulting rows (see documentation for details).
map_df(m, ~ df %>%
        filter(format(StartDate, f) <=  .x &
                format(EndDate, f)  >= .x) %>%
        group_by(month = .x) %>%
        count()
)

# For the data.frame you provided this is the result:
## A tibble: 18 x 2
## Groups:   month [18]
#   month       n
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 2018-01     1
# 2 2018-02     1
# 3 2018-03     2
# 4 2018-04     2
# 5 2018-05     3
# 6 2018-06     4
# 7 2018-07     5
# 8 2018-08     5
# 9 2018-09     5
#10 2018-10     5
#11 2018-11     5
#12 2018-12     5
#13 2019-01     4
#14 2019-02     4
#15 2019-03     3
#16 2019-04     3
#17 2019-05     2
#18 2019-06     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr`.

Some example data to get a data frame of dates :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(as.Date(c("2018-05-02", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-04", "2018-05-04", "2018-05-02", "2018-06-03", "2018-06-04", "2018-07-04", "2018-07-04"))) %>%
    rename(Date = 1)
```

Add a column that specifies the numeric month:

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(Month = month(Date))
```

Create a data frame of numeric months (1-12) and give it a blank column for subscription count called 'subs'.

```
subs_by_month <- as.tibble(1:12) %>% 
    rename(Month = 1)
subs_by_month$subs <- NA
```

Loop through using `tally` to count the number of observations:

```
for(i in 1:12){
  subs_by_month$subs[[i]] <- unlist(
    df %>%
    tally(Month==i)
    )
}
```

The resulting frame has the numeric month and number of subs per that month.